# Query to search tree in database

Tags: sql, ms-access, nested-sets, tree

I have a table in my database representing a tree. The data is stored using [nested sets](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). I want to write a query to search the tree and return just the nodes that match a pattern, along with their ancestors and descendants. This is what I have come up with so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Node, Parent, Description
FROM Hierarchy 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Lft, Rgt 
    FROM Hierarchy 
    WHERE Description LIKE '%SEARCHQUERY%') AS Matches 
ON (Hierarchy.Lft <= Matches.Lft AND 
    Hierarchy.Rgt >= Matches.Rgt) OR 
    (Hierarchy.Lft >= Matches.Lft AND 
    Hierarchy.Rgt <= Matches.Rgt) 
ORDER BY Description
```

This query works, but it's a little slow when the subquery matches a lot of descriptions. I'm looking for ideas on how to improve the performance of this query.

In case it's relevant, I'm using Access.

I am free and willing to change the structure of the table to improve this query. The table has about 8000 nodes. The number of records won't change much through the lifetime of the application. The maximum depth is five.

The performance is acceptable for regular searches (a few seconds for searches that return ~200 nodes), but on pathological cases it takes a few minutes (if searching for a single vowel, for example. But even in these instances, the subquery takes less than a second to execute).

Comment: Do you have indexes on the rgt and lft columns of hierarchy?

Comment: No, I didn't have indexes -- I added them, but it only improved speed a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the link to nested sets.

Comment: Well typically i wouldnt use a seperate table to store the set i would have the Rgt,Lft, and Parent columns directly on the table for the nodes the fact that youre doing a join couple with the `LIKE` condition is likely the cause of the slowness. Of course to change that in the schema is fairly radical changewise given what youve already got going on.

Comment: I'm not using a separate table for the Lft, Rgt, and Parent columns. They're all in the same table. I'm joining the table against itself in the query, so that might make it a little confusing.

Comment: Nested sets are not very good performance-wise (at least according to Stephen Faroult, who discussed this topic at length in his "Art of SQL"). Could you consider a different approach for trees or is it too late for that?

How many rows are you typically working on? The query is "a little slow" but something like "it takes 2 seconds on a 1000 rows table, and I expect the full system to have 22000 rows in it" could help.

I'd also try to profile the inner scan alone (i.e.: SELECT Lft, Rgt FROM Hierarchy WHERE Description LIKE '%SEARCHQUERY%'): "free text" searches are often usually slow in DBs.

Comment: I updated the question to address your comments. Would you recommend "Art of SQL"?

Comment: I read both "SQL for Smarties" and "The Art of SQL". Granted, years passed between the two books, and it's of course subjective, but I found "The Art of SQL" better in terms of how practical/useful it could be. Faroult seems more pragmatic than Celko, to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am probably straying a bit from the original question, but here I go:

As suggested in the comments, considering you can afford a rewrite, you should investigate a different way to model your tree structure, especially considering you have a "fixed depth" that is pretty manageable with a different approach.

Faroult in his "The Art of SQL" favours an approach based on representing the position of the node in a string field encoding the "branch" the node lives on. (For a review of the book, and a bit of discussion, see **[this Slashdot thread](http://news.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=06/06/07/1458232)**).

Here is an **[online example](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TreeInSql)** of what I mean - The Art of SQL has a whole section of the book dedicated to this, comparing three different approaches (Nested Sets, Parent/Child relation table, Encoded path field) and using the battle order of the armies at Waterloo as an example (with plenty of queries like "List all the battalions under General X" or "Find who was the commander of Artillery Group Y").

Faroult is pretty fanatic about performance and the whole book is a non-vendor specific collection of very sound and practical advice on how to (re)write efficient queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use just a `parent_id` field in the table, and use a 3-way outer self-join to get the target `hierarchy` records (filtered appropriately) plus their parent (if any) and  child (if any) records.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it only gets one parent and one level of children. I want to get all ancestors (parents and parents of parents, and so on) and descendants (children, children's children, ...).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your query is slow is the `LIKE('%blah%')` part. If you can drop the first `%` things will speed up appreciably.  Or, **if** Access supports FULLTEXT indices, then put one on the Description field and do `MATCH(Description) AGAINST ('blah')`

Comment: Jet/ACE does not support full-text indexes of any kind.